# Write SW in a hazard-free assembly code for mips

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I am designing a 32-bit pipeline mips with VHDL which includes no unit to detect hazards. So in order to test the structure, I need to have vectors of hazard-free assembly codes in my testbench.

Looking at Patterson Computer organization book, I found an exercise which says the following set of codes are hazard free:

```
--lw $t1, 0($t0) 
--lw $t2, 4($t0) 
--lw $t4, 8($t0)
--add $t3, $t1,$t2 
--sw $t3, 12($t0) 
--add $t5, $t1, $t4 
--sw $t5, 16($t0)
```

However, I guess the SW is causing hazards here. Please kindly let me know how to sort this code in a way that I can have an assembly code with no hazards.

Also, if I want to add other R-Type assembly codes, should I include "NOOP"s or there is yet another way to do it?

Comment: Why do you believe the `sw` to have a hazard?

Comment: In line 4 and 5, sw is storing in $t3, doesn't that make a structural hazard?

Comment: Well, what about something like `add $t0, $a0, $a1; add $t1, $t0, $t0`? For something like that to work without bubbles in a pipelined microarchitecture you need bypasses. For your problem, AFAICT you just need an extra multiplexer for the data input of the memory operation.

Comment: Can you explain more about the multiplexer? I cannot figure out how it can work.

Comment: Well, do you know how `add $t0, $a0, $a1` directly followed by `add $t1, $t0, $t0` can avoid stalling the pipeline?

Comment: They are completely independent in terms of variables and addresses.  So, there will be no stalls in any of the stages of the pipeline. These adds can replace the lw command right?

Comment: None of what you have said is anywhere close to correct.